# Displaying contents of an Excel file in a Java SWT GUI

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, swt, windowbuilder

I am developing a password manager within Eclipse and I am using Windowbuilder to help. I am using SWT, and am trying to make use of an Excel file which would store information such as usernames, passwords and additional notes
[This is what I have so far when the program is launched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0veTR.png)

The left part, where there is a patch of white is where I want a menu to navigate through the Excel file, but I can not start that yet as I do not know how to actually display the Excel file. The area on the right which is not being used is where I want the information to be displayed
[This is a sketch of what I would want it to be similar to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyD48.png)

The Excel file can be any type, as long as it works with the GUI. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

one suggestion is to create a workbook with multiple sheets by the name of your menu like Gmail, accounts etc. then create columns by name of the information you want to store which would be website, username, password etc. Then Use [apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) to read the file in java. This [Tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-read-excel-file-in-java) will help you in reading the excel file.
Regarding display of excel file, You can use [Table Editor](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Table-viewer/table_viewer.html) to display your data.